# exposing oData via BizTalk Service

Tags: json, rest, odata, biztalk

Using BizTalk I'm looking for a solution to expose a Service receiving oData request as in IE Browser and then returning back oData json/xml? e.g.

```
Request:
http://localhost/odata/Employees
Response:
oData or employees records in json or xml.
```

It should be replica of same EF Model based ASP WebServices which return back oData using Controllers.

Any simple way to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to host this in BizTalk as opposed to a regular WCF or ASP.NET service?

Comment: Yes Dan, we want to route all traffic via BizTalk and not creating service on its own.

Comment: Well, yes, you just use the REST and JSON support in BizTalk Server.  Have you tried anything?  Is there a specific issue/problem you're facing?

Comment: Yes i tried but the only issue is replicating the existing system where it works and expects same input/output just as IE. Another thing is to expose database on EF model. I have not tried adding DataModel to BT assembly yet, So I have to try to pass incoming URL to oDAta Controller from Orch.  so not sure if that model works from an orch containing Dll.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure this is a full answer, and it's probably not what you want to hear, but here are my thoughts:

1. It'd be non-trivial to do a full oData implementation using just BizTalk's REST and WCF facilities.  It's probably possible though.
2. Your best bet for it would be to write some custom adapter/pipeline/orchestration that wraps the functionality of [`Microsoft.Services.Data`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services/) - in other words, hosts the WCF service as if it was running in BizTalk (much like the other WCF adapters).  Again, this is not a trivial task, and I'm not sure there's an existing adapter for this (there a proprietary one to query oData services, but not to handle queries).
3. Alternatively, if you just want a subset of oData functionality, just implement that functionality in a `WebHTTP` service using `JSON` functionality.  This is probably more doable, assuming your use cases are fairly limitted.

It would probably be more straightforward to simply write a WCF service implementing `Microsoft.Services.Data` and made appropriate calls to the BAM API and/or BRE API as needed.  If you had it publish certain messages to a BizTalk endpoint, you're basically going down the path of #2 (custom adapter).  That's only worth going down if you really need the tracking/throttling/reliability that BizTalk will provide.